# Is there a way to simply query the YouTube Data Api for information about a url?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

It seems like pretty common problem/question on here to ask how to parse a YouTube video/user/channel/playlist url; with a lot of the answers being partial or outdated regex solutions (Meaning they don't support legacy urls or newer features like handles). Which made me wonder..

Can I simply just ask the v3 Youtube Data Api if a url is valid; then have it return any relevant information?  (similar to doing a search w/the api, it'll tell you the type, id, etc.)

As far as I can tell from the reference it's not entirely possible.

The closest I could find was doing a search with the url as the query, but this unsurprisingly led to getting a list with somewhat unpredictable results.

**Edit:** I've requested the feature [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/269959744), if anyone else would find a feature like this useful please star it and/or comment, because their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) states that feature-requests aren't entirely put on their radar until multiple people request/star.

Comment: YouTube Data API doesn't have a feature that check if a url is valid. Get yourself familiar with the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  As I mentioned above, I read through the reference/documentation, and even used the search functionality in the api.  This question is more about making sure there isn't an alternative way to do this or something I missed.